# Event Jquery UI in dart

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dart, dart-html, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to get Event object in listener function of a Jquery Ui Element.
I'm actually programming in dart language and use the js package (dart:js)
Here is an example :

Example.html :

```
<script async type="application/dart" src="Example.dart"></script>
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <canvas id="stage" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <button id="btnImport">Button Import</button>
  <div id="slider-1"></div>
</div>
```

Example.dart :

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

void main() {
  js.JsObject slider_1 = js.context.callMethod("\$", ['#slider-1']);
  slider_1.callMethod('slider');
  slider_1.callMethod("on",["slidechange",_onSliderChange]);
}

void _onSliderChange(js.JsObject obj1,js.JsObject obj2) {

}
```

How i retrieve the Event Object of slidechange event in _onSliderChange function?
JsOjbect don't really help me...
Ty

Comment: I just research to have the reaction of a normaly event listener.
I'm used to receive Event object in function listener and work with it.
In your answer, my debugger never go to  "var event.." line. 
The listener seems to be not initalize with just querySelector.

I will use Jquery UI element and work with it in dart.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the jquery-ui element API doc you are using? If it's this http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/ it doesn't fire a `slidechange` event. maybe you want listen to the `change` event instead.

Comment: I just tried your code and `_onSliderChange` is called when I move the knob.

Comment: but do you can retrieve the event object ?

Comment: What information do you want to get out from the event object? I get a value passed but I don't know what to check for.

Comment: event object ->target ->relatedTarget
or the ui object that change event get (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#entry-examples)

do you can see what's JsObject are composed ? I can't analyse it in debugger of DartEditor :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you cannot retrieve the event itself but just a js version of a jquery event (not native dom event) so you need to know how it looks like to read the property you want according to the doc in http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

```
void _onSliderChange(js.JsObject obj1, js.JsObject obj2) {
  print(obj1['target']); // <= get the div
  print(obj2['value']);  // <= get the value
}
```

which should display, as you move the slider, something like

```
div (:1)
5 (:1)
```

As you said, it is sometimes hard to deal/debug JsObject so I wrote some helpers to convert such object to dart collection (list or map) for debugging purpose here https://github.com/alextekartik/tekartik_utils.dart/blob/master/lib/src/js_utils/jsobject_converter.dart

```
void _onSliderChange(js.JsObject obj1,js.JsObject obj2) {
  print(jsObjectKeys(obj1));
  print(jsObjectAsCollection(obj1));
}
```

which should display stuff like

```
[originalEvent, type, isDefaultPrevented, timeStamp, jQuery110207535289276856929, target, toElement, screenY, screenX, pageY, pageX, offsetY, offsetX, fromElement, clientY, clientX, buttons, button, which, view, shiftKey, relatedTarget, metaKey, eventPhase, currentTarget, ctrlKey, cancelable, bubbles, altKey, delegateTarget, handleObj, data, isTrigger, namespace, namespace_re, result] (:1)
{originalEvent: {originalEvent: Instance of 'MouseEvent', type: mouseup, isDefaultPrevented: {}, timeStamp: 1409328507659, jQuery110207535289276856929: true, toElement: span, screenY: 624, screenX: 115, pageY: 545, pageX: 110, offsetY: 16, offsetX: 15, fromElement: null, clientY: 545, clientX: 110, buttons: null, button: 0, which: 1, view: <window>, target: span, shiftKey: false, relatedTarget: null, metaKey: false, eventPhase: 3, currentTarget: Instance of 'HtmlDocument', ctrlKey: false, cancelable: true, bubbles: true, altKey: false, delegateTarget: Instance of 'HtmlDocument', handleObj: {type: mouseup, origType: mouseup, data: null, handler: {guid: 23}, guid: 23, selector: null, needsContext: null, namespace: slider}, data: null}, type: slidechange, isDefaultPrevented: {}, timeStamp: 1409328507659, jQuery110207535289276856929: true, target: div, toElement: span, screenY: 624, screenX: 115, pageY: 545, pageX: 110, offsetY: 16, offsetX: 15, fromElement: null, clientY: 545, clientX: 110, buttons: null, button: 0, which: 1, view: <window>, shiftKey: false, relatedTarget: null, metaKey: false, eventPhase: 3, currentTarget: div, ctrlKey: false, cancelable: true, bubbles: true, altKey: false, delegateTarget: div, handleObj: {type: slidechange, origType: slidechange, data: null, handler: {guid: 17}, guid: 17, selector: null, needsContext: null, namespace: }, data: null, isTrigger: 3, namespace: , namespace_re: null, result: null} (:1)
```

where you can likely find the property you want from the event

Comment: Perfect ! So simple ! I'll try your object helper soon as possible.
Thanks for your help and Günter Zöchbauer, thank's you too.